# Trying to define a formula in excel

Tags: excel

I need to define a formula for a new column without dragging the cells such that the first row is zero and each subsequent row takes the value of the previous row and adds two to it. Is this possible to do using excel?

Comment: `sequence` if you have office 365 is probably what you want.

Comment: Not using office 365 but just regular Microsoft excel

Comment: @NikitaJaitly then you cannot get away from dragging the formula down when using formula.  Older versions require a formula in each cell.  But you can do a [Fill series](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/fill-series/how-to-fill-series), but that still requires you to select the cells into which you want to fill the series.  The formula you want is: `=IF(ROW(A1)=1,0,(ROW(A1)-1)*2+2)` and copy/drag down.